# Display Stored Procedure results into Server Explorer

Tags: stored-procedures, server-explorer

I do not have admin panel on my website (I find it overkill) and use default local MS Studio Server Explorer to admin my website's database. I use Views and it works great for my purposes. But now I need parametrized View and I created Stored Procedure. But I didn't find a way how to display result set of SP as View does it. It sends data to Output window instead of Server Explorer's grid view. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can run the stored proc using "EXEC", this will put the results in a grid at the bottom of the screen. i.e.

```
exec mySp 'Param'
```

Comment: It really does it as I want when I execute it in "New Query" window but how can I save it to Views or Stored Procedures and use "Run Stored Procedure" dialog to set parameter?